# JavaScript - How do I stop a script from working if the screen height smaller than 790px?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code which I would like to stop working if the screen height smaller than 790px:

```
$(function() {
    if ($("#PopularPosts1").length) {
        var o = $("#PopularPosts1"),
            t = $("#PopularPosts1").offset().top,
            i = $("#PopularPosts1").height();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var s = $("#upfooter2").offset().top - i - 20,
                f = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (f > t ? o.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: 48,
                    width: 318
                }) : o.css("position", "static"), f > s) {
                var n = s - f;
                o.css({
                    top: n
                })
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent this code from running then you can use the line below.

```
$(function() {
    if($(window).height() > 790){ // Evaluate if the height of the window is greater than 790.
      if ($("#PopularPosts1").length) {
          var o = $("#PopularPosts1"),
              t = $("#PopularPosts1").offset().top,
              i = $("#PopularPosts1").height();
          $(window).scroll(function() {
              var s = $("#upfooter2").offset().top - i - 20,
                  f = $(window).scrollTop();
              if (f > t ? o.css({
                      position: "fixed",
                      top: 48,
                      width: 318
                  }) : o.css("position", "static"), f > s) {
                  var n = s - f;
                  o.css({
                      top: n
                  })
              }
          })
      }
    }
});
```